# Proper way to use AJAX Post in jquery to pass model from strongly typed MVC3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm a novice web programmer so please forgive me if some of my "jargon" is not correct.
I've got a project using ASP.NET using the MVC3 framework.

I am working on an admin view where the admin will modify a list of equipment.  One of the functions is an "update" button that I want to use jquery to dynamically edit the entry on the webpage after sending a post to the MVC controller.

I presume this approach is "safe" in a single admin setting where there is minimal concern of the webpage getting out of sync with the database.

I've created a view that is strongly typed and was hoping to pass the model data to the MVC control using an AJAX post.

In the following post, I found something that is similar to what I am looking at doing:
[JQuery Ajax and ASP.NET MVC3 causing null parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698888/jquery-ajax-and-asp-net-mvc3-causing-null-parameters)

I will use the code sample from the above post.

Model:

```
public class AddressInfo 
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Check(AddressInfo addressInfo)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

script in View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ai = {
    Address1: "423 Judy Road",
    Address2: "1001",
    City: "New York",
    State: "NY",
    ZipCode: "10301",
    Country: "USA"
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/home/check',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(ai),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data.success) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
</script>
```

I have not had a chance to use the above yet.  But I was wondering if this was the "best" method to pass the model data back to the MVC control using AJAX?

Should I be concerned about exposing the model information?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can skip the var declaration and the stringify. Otherwise, that will work just fine.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/check',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        Address1: "423 Judy Road",
        Address2: "1001",
        City: "New York",
        State: "NY",
        ZipCode: "10301",
        Country: "USA"
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.success);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the slight adjustment.  Is there any concern with exposing the model structure from a security standpoint?

Comment: Nothing glaring stands out as a security issue to me. If you're really concerned about it though, you can always make a custom model binder on the mvc side.

Comment: This failed for me. I had to use JSON.stringify( { ... } ) for the call to work in MVC5.

Comment: I've noticed that I have to do the same when working with API controllers. This answer was written 4 years ago though, before API controllers existed.

Comment: god damit, I had dataType instead of contentType, that one always always gets me!!

Answer (score 178):

I found 3 ways to implement this:

C# class:

```
public class AddressInfo {
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Check(AddressInfo addressInfo)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

**JavaScript** you can do it three ways:

1)       Query String:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/en/Home/Check',
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
});
```

Data here is a string.

`"Address1=blah&Address2=blah&City=blah&State=blah&ZipCode=blah&Country=blah"`

2)       Object Array:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/en/Home/Check',
    data: $('#form').serializeArray(),
    type: 'POST',
});
```

Data here is an array of key/value pairs :

```
=[{name: 'Address1', value: 'blah'}, {name: 'Address2', value: 'blah'}, {name: 'City', value: 'blah'}, {name: 'State', value: 'blah'}, {name: 'ZipCode', value: 'blah'}, {name: 'Country', value: 'blah'}]
```

3)       JSON:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/en/Home/Check',
      data: JSON.stringify({ addressInfo:{//missing brackets
          Address1: $('#address1').val(),
          Address2: $('#address2').val(),
          City: $('#City').val(),
          State: $('#State').val(),
          ZipCode: $('#ZipCode').val()}}),
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Data here is a serialized JSON string. Note that the name has to match the parameter name in the server!!

```
='{"addressInfo":{"Address1":"blah","Address2":"blah","City":"blah","State":"blah", "ZipCode", "blah", "Country", "blah"}}'
```

Comment: Just came across this great, thorough answer which solved questions I didn't know I had yet. +1, thanks!

Comment: #2 was what I was looking for. This should be the answer.

Comment: EDIT: had to use `data: $('input, textarea, select').serialize(),` for mine to work.

Comment: Hey Jazaret!! how to pass date to model with 3rd approach??

Comment: Sorry for the delay @GuruprasadRao To pass a date you can have the date & time be a string in the javascript code and MVC will translate it to a DateTime object.

Comment: @Jazaret Do the properties have to be in the same order as they are in the viewmodel?

Comment: @tcrite I don't believe they need to be in the same order.

Comment: @Jazaret Thanks. I figured out my issue. Some of my property names weren't matching up in a collection that was a property of the serialized object.

Comment: When using method 3 (JSON), the name of the parameter in the controller action is not required i.e. in this case 'addressInfo:', only { } is enough. Probably needed in the case of multiple action parameters.

Comment: is there any way to get intellisense to avoid the typos which are very much possible as happened with @tcrite.

Comment: Option number 3 saved my life! The name must match the parameter name in the controller function was throwing me off for days! Thanks for this answer, should be the selected answer.

Comment: This is a bit late in the game but I'd argue you shouldn't use option 1 because a POST request shouldn't be exposing values in the query string.  It could also be viewed as a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 12):

This is the way it worked for me:

```
$.post("/Controller/Action", $("#form").serialize(), function(json) {       
        // handle response
}, "json");

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TV(MyModel id)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

what you have is fine - however to save some typing, you can simply use for your data

```
data: $('#formId').serialize()
```

see http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2009/05/04/how-to-use-jquery-to-serialize-ajax-forms/ for details, the syntax is pretty basic.

Comment: In order to use the serialize function, my understanding is that each member of the class needs to be used in a form object.  If that is correct, I may be SOL.

Comment: ah ya.. if not you cant use serialize then. you can always manipulate the DOM though and create a form with those elements and serialize it - but... it would likely be cleaner to just have the fields manually typed out then.

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui serialize indeed works in IE, what doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: every property of my model is coming out null

Comment: @TahaRehmanSiddiqui do the 'name' of your form fields match the names of your model properties?

Comment: found my problem, I actually had all the properties listed as the function's parameters. And that does not work in IE. I have not tried receiving a model directly in the function.

Answer (score 0):

**If using MVC 5 read this solution!**

I know the question specifically called for MVC 3, but I stumbled upon this page with MVC 5 and wanted to post a solution for anyone else in my situation. I tried the above solutions, but they did not work for me, the Action Filter was never reached and I couldn't figure out why. I am using version 5 in my project and ended up with the following action filter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Filters;

namespace SydHeller.Filters
{
    public class ValidateJSONAntiForgeryHeader : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            string clientToken = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Get(KEY_NAME);
            if (clientToken == null)
            {
                throw new HttpAntiForgeryException(string.Format("Header does not contain {0}", KEY_NAME));
            }

            string serverToken = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get(KEY_NAME).Value;
            if (serverToken == null)
            {
                throw new HttpAntiForgeryException(string.Format("Cookies does not contain {0}", KEY_NAME));
            }

            System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(serverToken, clientToken);
        }

        private const string KEY_NAME = "__RequestVerificationToken";
    }
}
```

-- Make note of the `using System.Web.Mvc` and `using System.Web.Mvc.Filters`, not the `http` libraries (I think that is one of the things that changed with MVC v5. --

Then just apply the filter `[ValidateJSONAntiForgeryHeader]` to your action (or controller) and it should get called correctly.

In my layout page right above `</body>` I have `@AntiForgery.GetHtml();`

Finally, in my Razor page, I do the ajax call as follows:

```
var formForgeryToken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: serviceURL,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: requestData,
  headers: {
     "__RequestVerificationToken": formForgeryToken
  },
     success: crimeDataSuccessFunc,
     error: crimeDataErrorFunc
});
```

Comment: Are you retrieving all your form values manually? Why not `data: $("#the-form").serialize()`?

Comment: @Sinjai I would have to look at my code again, but I believe I am doing some other processing in there as well. ".serialize()" would also work if you just need the input values

Comment: No worries, I was just curious.