# Ajax sucess function not called (returning data)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a simple $.ajax call that i did a million times before

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,              
  sucess: function (data) {
          alert(data);
          }
});
```

and a controller that accepts my data without a problem but i can't seem to return data to the `sucess` function.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyClass data)
{
   //do something
   return Content("blabla");           

}
```

What seems to be the problem?

EDIT:
Everything was ok but i wrote `sucess` instead of `success`.

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,              
      success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
              }
    });
```

Comment: Look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980389/proper-way-to-use-ajax-post-in-jquery-to-pass-model-from-strongly-typed-mvc3-vie

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need to return a json-p style response... if the javascript and server side code are running on different domains then this is almost certainly the case.
Take a looks at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for some more details.

I suggest you try :

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  datatype: "text",
  async: false,
  url: url,
  data: data,              
  sucess: function (data) {
          alert(data);
          }
});
```

The idea is if you ask for a synchronous call and request type of text then it should get around the jsonp / callback issue.

Hopefully worth a try :)

Comment: thanks but the problem was in my tired eyes. I wrote sucess instead of success as you did too in the response, still thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Do'oh, sometime the simplest mistakes are the tough ones to spot. glad you got it working :)