# How to use UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl() in jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the below c#.net code which works and returns me the url.I want to write equivalent code from javascript/jquery .

```
HttpContextBase httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
Uri uri = httpContext.Request.Url;
string url = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(imageSource, httpContext);
```

Is there any way I can write its equivalent code in the jquery/javascript or is there a way I can call this c# code from javascript if I have it in a method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to use AJAX Post in jquery to pass model from strongly typed MVC3 view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980389/proper-way-to-use-ajax-post-in-jquery-to-pass-model-from-strongly-typed-mvc3-vie)

Comment: That link is informative, but not helpful for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write a JavaScript/jQuery equivalent code for C# server side code.

All you can do is, render the server side string variable into a JavaScript variable of your view.

There are many ways to do. But you could make use of ViewBag in this case.

***Using ViewBag***

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
 HttpContextBase httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
 Uri uri = httpContext.Request.Url;
 ViewBag.MyUrl= UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(imageSource, httpContext);
 return View();
}
```

then in a View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myUrl='@ViewBag.MyUrl';
</script>
```

***Embed it in a view***

```
@{

HttpContextBase httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
Uri uri = httpContext.Request.Url;
String url = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(imageSource, httpContext);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
var myUrl='@url';
</script>
```