# Asp.net mvc pass parameter to controller from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I new to asp.net mvc technology.

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult SessionData()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When button pressed on the view I need to implement ajax call and pass two strings to the controller above.

My question is how make ajax calls in asp.net mvc?Can I use HTML helper to generate ajax function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to use AJAX Post in jquery to pass model from strongly typed MVC3 view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980389/proper-way-to-use-ajax-post-in-jquery-to-pass-model-from-strongly-typed-mvc3-vie)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            arg1: 'value1',
            arg2: 'value2'
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('Successfully passed data to controller');
        }
    });
</script>
```

and the corresponding controller action may look like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string arg1, string arg2)
{
    ... do something with those arguments and return a result

    return Json(new
    {
        someProperty = "some value"
    });
}
```