# Loading data in view after click the button without reload all data in page asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I need to load all of comments after click button "all comments" without reload page. 
I have "News" page with comments, after load page we can see one comment below the text news. All data situated in table rows. I have two rows. One row have button "All comments", second row have textbox from comments and button "Add new comment". 
I need after click button "All comments" load all list comments (dynamic load rows with data) without reload page. And I need to add comment in database after click button "Add new comment" without reload page too. 
I don't know how to do this.

I have combined model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NarkomApp.Models

{
    public class News_CommentsModel
    {
        public NEWS newsModel { get; set; }
    public List<COMMENTS> commentsModel { get; set; }

    public List<NEWS> recomendNewsModel { get; set; }
    public List<NEWS> waterShutOffModel { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Code view:

```
<tr class="trDiscussion">

                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="gray"></div>
                        <div class="interesting">
                            <p>Обсуждение</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr class="trComments">

                    <td width="100%" height="auto" colspan="2">
                        <div class="comments">

                            @{
                                if (Model.commentsModel.Count != 0)
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.commentsModel.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        <p>@Model.commentsModel[i].sUserName</p>
                                        <p><a class="date-comment">@Model.commentsModel[i].vDateTime</a></p>
                                        <p class="text-comment">@Model.commentsModel[i].vComment</p>
                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <p>Комментариев нет</p>
                                }
                            }


                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr class="trButtonShowAllComments">

                    <td colspan="2" height="50px">
                        <div>
                            <a class="comm" role="button" href="#">Все комментарии</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr class="trAddNewComment">

                    <td width="100%" height="auto" colspan="2">
                        @{
                            if (Session["iIdUsers"] == null)
                            {
                                <div class="new-comment">
                                    Вы не авторизированы, для того, чтобы оставлять коментарии войдите под своим аккаунтом: @Html.ActionLink("Войти", "LogIn", "Home")                                        
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="new-comment">
                                    <p>Новый комментарий:</p>
                                </div>
                                <textarea class="message" size="40" name="search" placeholder=""></textarea>
                                <div>
                                    <a class="send" role="button" href="#">Отправить</a>
                                </div>
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery ajax post or get method to extract or send data using jquery.

[sample jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

[sample asp mvc with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980389/proper-way-to-use-ajax-post-in-jquery-to-pass-model-from-strongly-typed-mvc3-vie)

hope I help you

Answer (score 0):

Think you should read about Asp.net WebApi, or doing some tricky stuff by implementing api function inside your regular mvc controller, which would return page with only json-serialized data. And of course use ajax(or just XmlHttpRequest if you don't want to load external library) to retrieve tha data from apropreate api action