# Modal creating a log without changing the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My page display a list of question. Near each question, a button switch a hidden statement to display a model over the page asking for some information. The goal would be, after the user complete the information and click submit, to access the backend and send the information to the database WITHOUT loading another page. I would like this popup to close and the user to resume what he was doing as if he did not do anything.

How would I go about doing something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax and send a Post HttpRequest to an action which would then be tasked to save those information.

Please refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980389/proper-way-to-use-ajax-post-in-jquery-to-pass-model-from-strongly-typed-mvc3-vie) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/post-the-data-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-using-jquery-ajax) for more info.

Hope this helps you.