# Null parameter when use Ajax post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have found several answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698888/jquery-ajax-and-asp-net-mvc3-causing-null-parameters) for example) but they do not seem to solve my problem.

```
                var result = {
                    command: 'exportWAV',
                    type: type
                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'SubmitSound',
                    type: 'Post',
                    data: JSON.stringify(result),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                    }
                });
```

Back end code

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitSound(string blob)
        {
            // Create the new, empty data file.
            string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Content/Sound/" + Environment.TickCount + ".wav";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

            w.Write(blob);
            w.Close();
            fs.Close();           
            return new JsonResult() { Data = "Saved successfully" };
        }
```

`result` is not null because `this.postMessage = result;` send a file back to client side for downloading. `w.Write(blob)` keeps complaining that `blob` cannot be `null`.

How can I make it work? Thank you and best regards

Comment: I dont see like `blob = result`

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ blob: result}),
```

You may want to change your `string` param in your controller action, for an object with the same structure of your JSON... that means the same attributes names.

The object should be something like this:

```
public class MyBlob{
  public string command {get; set;}
  public string type {get; set;}
}
```

So, your action should be:

```
 public ActionResult SubmitSound(MyBlob blob){
    //Here your action logic
 }
```

Comment: Now both `command` and `type` is null, I guess I have not diged it deep enough. Thank you for your idea